# Set Lat and Long to Google Maps Marker position flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am trying to add latitude and longitude values to the position: parameter in the Marker type for Google maps. I have the values but I don't know how to add them to the parameter.

Here is what I have:

```
position: LatLng(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude + "," + PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude),
```

I know what I am doing is wrong because I am trying to treat a double as a string.
The definition of LatLng is (double Latitude, double Longitude)

What is the proper way to add these values to the LatLng?

Thanks

I added the code below and now I get a null error:

```
position: LatLng(double.tryParse(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude) ?? 0.0 , double.tryParse(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude) ?? 0.0)
```

Here is the error message I get when I hover over .latitude:
[image]

How do I address this null type?

Answer (score 0):

```
///
/// If [PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude] or [PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude] is a string, then it will be converted to double 
///

LatLng(double.tryParse(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude) ?? 0.0 , double.tryParse(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude) ?? 0.0)



/// 
/// Otherwise, its value will be used as it is
/// 

LatLng(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude  , PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried both lines of code you responded with and I get the same error with both. I put the error in the original post.

Comment: I found the answer to my error:  position: LatLng(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude!,
                  PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude!)